# I have a 10/2 home run , it got nicked by a drill and damaged the exterior sheathing, not sure if wire itself was hit, how should I fix it?

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair

It’s located in a ceiling, it’s a home run to a stairwell heater. Building is drywalled and painted.

Comment: The fix really depends on if you hit the wire or not. You'll have to know that.

Comment: Do you *want* your house to burn down? If not, open up the ceiling and take a better look. If there’s damage you’ll need to splice in a repair.

Answer (score 1):

Wires in cable are individually insulated, so hopefully that insulation is not damaged.

You will need to get a good look at the nick. The actual damage will determine the repair. This is all assuming the wire is not broken. That would obviously need a splice in a box opening up another issue.

If the exterior sheathing is the only part that was damaged and you can see that there is no copper wire showing, you should be good with a wrap with electrical tape.

If copper wire is showing the insulation is damaged. You need to get to more of the sheathing to remove it.  Remove enough to get a good wrap around the exposed wire. Then wrap the entire cable about 2 inches over each end of original sheathing. Obviously encompassing all 3 wires.